# flash problem after installed nvidia

Tags: nvidia, flash, xserver

a few days ago I install nvidia xserver because I have a monitor (DELE207WFP) with was saw with maximum resolution 1024x740, and I read that on xserver is possible to write own monitor configuration. I write that driver with tutorial: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12937, and this works (but a shape are little blurred). I restarted my computer and than when i go to youtube i can see any video

[image]

I now I don't know how to do with this, my only idea is to uninstall xserver, but i need it to use monitor, without nvidia driver the screen size is 1024 rather than 1650 and This makes it impossible to work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the very latest driver from nvidia

Add the  PPA for nvidia

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Update software sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Download the driver

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot

This fixes many nvidia issues so may help you